# Render in React Native interferes with variable update

Tags: react-native, variables, storage, render

I have the following code written in React Native.  As can be seen, a function within 'componentDidMount' is called ('getKey') that is used to retrieve some variables previously saved from storage:

```
export default class Cast extends Component {
constructor(props) {
 super(props);

 this.state = {
  admin: false,
  isPublishing: false,
  userComment: "",
  hasPermission: false,
  paused: true,
  _email: false,
  _name: false,
  _pword: false,
  _play_ID: false,
  _streamkey: false,
  _playurl: "",
  _streamurl: "",
  isLoading : true,
 };
}

getKey = async() => {
  try {
    var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('email');
    this.setState({ _email: value });
    value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('playkey');
    this.setState({ _play_ID: value });
    const playurl = "https://stream.mux.com/" + value + ".m3u8"
    this.setState({ _playurl: playurl });
    value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('castkey');
    this.setState({ _streamkey: value });
    const streamurl = "rtmp://global-live.mux.com:5222/app/" + value
    this.setState({ _streamurl: streamurl });
    this.setState({ isLoading: false });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error retrieving data" + error);
  }
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.getKey();
}

renderCameraView = () => {

  return (
    <NodeCameraView
      style={styles.nodeCameraView}
      /* eslint-disable */
      ref={vb => {
        this.vb = vb;
      }}
      /* eslint-enable */
      outputUrl = {this.state._streamurl}
      camera={settings.camera}
      audio={settings.audio}
      video={settings.video}
      autopreview
    />
  );
};

renderPlayerView = () => {

const { paused } = this.state;
const source = {
  uri: _playurl  //THROWS A "VARIABLE NOT FOUND" ERROR...LIKELY DUE TO RENDER BEFORE VALUE IS RETREIVED FROM STORAGE...?  
};
  return (
    <Video
      source={source} // Can be a URL or a local file.
      /* eslint-disable */
      ref={ref => {
        this.player = ref;
      }} // Store reference
      /* eslint-enable */
      onBuffer={this.onBuffer} // Callback when remote video is buffering
      onError={this.onError} // Callback when video cannot be loaded
      style={styles.nodePlayerView}
      fullscreen={false}
      resizeMode="cover"
      paused={paused}
    />
  );
};

renderEmptyView = () => {
  const { paused } = this.state;
  const source = {
    uri: "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"
  };

  return (
    <Video
      source={source} // Can be a URL or a local file.
      /* eslint-disable */
      ref={ref => {
        this.player = ref;
      }} // Store reference
      /* eslint-enable */
      onBuffer={this.onBuffer} // Callback when remote video is buffering
      onError={this.onError} // Callback when video cannot be loaded
      style={styles.nodePlayerView}
      fullscreen={false}
      resizeMode="cover"
      paused={paused}
    />
  );

};

//...

render() {
  const { admin, paused, isPublishing } = this.state;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
     {isLoading ? this.renderEmptyView() : !isLoading && admin ? this.renderPlayerView() : !isLoading && !admin ? this.renderCameraView()} 


//...

    </View>
  );

//...
```

This code is mainly operative.  The problem is that the function 'renderPlayerView' is immediately called/rendered...as can be seen in the 'render' section at the bottom of the code.  As I understand...in React Native any render is performed BEFORE any other process.  I believe this is the cause of my problem.

The 'uri: _playurl' line within the 'renderPlayerView' function throws a 'variable not found' error or something similar.  Since the render is performed before anything else, I guess this makes sense to me as the value of the '_playurl' variable would not have yet been retrieved from storage.

Therefore my question is how could I pass the correct value (after retrieved from 'storage') to the '_playurl' variable FOLLOWING the render?  Or perhaps there is some sort of work-around?  I thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Isn't _playurl supposed to  be this.state._playurl? Been a while since I used class comps last time, might be wrong.

Comment: No that will throw an error...as will {this.state._playurl} (with the curly brackets)...I am somewhat sure problem is caused by the render performed before any variables are set as mentioned in my post.  Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a loader for this, just create a state and set its initial value to true and once you're done fetching the data from async storage set it to false. Then you should use this state to conditionally render the whole component.

like this:-

```
// 1. Create state
    state: {
    ...rest of your states,
    isLoading : true // ADD this   
    }

//2. Update state of isLoading once you are done fetching data
    getKey = async() => {
      try {
        ... your code
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error retrieving data" + error);
      } finally {
        this.setState({ loading: false });
     }
    }
    
//3. use the state to render your components conditionally
    
    render() {
      const { admin, paused, isPublishing, isLoading } = this.state;
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {isLoading  ?  <Loader/> //create some loader for your app (or simply use an activity indicator)
    : admin ? this.renderCameraView() : this.renderPlayerView()}  
    
    //...
    
        </View>
      );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Please see the edits I made to my original code.  Basically I added a 'constructor/super/this.state' in a vain attempt to pass props to the class from another page...and I made your suggestions.  I added a 'isLoading:false' variable and updated in my 'getKey' function.  The problem I have now is my ternary operator in the render section at the bottom of the code...it throws a syntax error.

Comment: According to "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator" I should be able to 'chain' these ternary operators...any idea what the problem is?  Thanks again for your reply!

Comment: {isLoading ? this.renderEmptyView() : !isLoading && admin ? this.renderPlayerView() : !isLoading && !admin ? this.renderCameraView() : null} - This will work

Comment: Thank you for your reply...I will be sure to try that out when I have an opportunity...it is appreciated!